# Is there a way to get a list of all existing HTML tags via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There is an exercise in a bootcamp I am attending which tasks one to create a jQuery like selector, here is part of the test:

```
describe("selectorTypeMatcher", function() {
  it("should return the 'id' type for an id selector", function() {
    var type = selectorTypeMatcher('#pagetitle');
    expect(type).toEqual("id");
  });

  it("should return the 'class' type for a class selector", function() {
    var type = selectorTypeMatcher('.image');
    expect(type).toEqual("class");
  });

  it("should return the 'tag.class' type for a tag.class selector", function() {
    var type = selectorTypeMatcher('img.thumbnail');
    expect(type).toEqual("tag.class");
  });

  it("should return the 'tag' type for a tag selector", function() {
    var type = selectorTypeMatcher('div');
    expect(type).toEqual("tag");
  });
});
```

The following is part of function which I created as described in the test spec.

```
var selectorTypeMatcher = function(selector) {
  if (selector.includes('#')) return 'id';
  if (selector.indexOf('.') == 0) return 'class';
  if (/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test() && selector.includes('.')) return 'tag.class';
};
```

I am stuck at the conditional which would check for a tag and class e.g. `div.foo`

I thought of created an array which would contain all existing tags...

```
var tags = ["a", "div", "span", "form", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"];
```

And then loop over them and see if that value was followed by an `.` for a class but that would be a lot of elements...

I thought of leveraging `document.querySelectorAll('*')` but that just...

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first
>   pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified
>   group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

But like it says ***Returns a list of the elements within the document***...

So is there an `API` that will return all of the existing html elements?

`html, head, body, div, p, span` etc.

Merci!

Comment: existing in a document or existing in the specification? `Array.from(new Set(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'), node => node.nodeName)))`

Comment: You should be using `queryselectorAll` . It returns all of the HTML elements because all elements exist within the document. JQuery uses `querySelectorAll` internally.

Comment: Hey Guys! I am looking for existing in the spec! But thanks my friends!

Comment: There should be no need for a list of tag names. A CSS-style selector will match against any pattern that forms a valid tag name, so it should match custom tags too. All you need is the generic definition of a valid tag name.

Comment: You can get all their constructor names with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter(k=>{
try{ return HTMLElement.isPrototypeOf(window[k])}
catch(e){}
})` but to get their tagName would require being able to create these, which must be done with `Document.createElement(tagName)`... Oh and actually this code will also return HTMLMediaElement, which is the proto of other HTMLElements, so it's not entirely reliable either...

Comment: _"I am stuck at the conditional which would check for a tag and class e.g. `div.foo`"_ , _"So is there an `API` that will return all of the existing html elements?"_ Is requirement to match a specific selector or get all HTML elements within a document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HTMLUnknownElement` object to check for a valid tag by specification:

```
if (tagIsValid(selector))
  return 'tag';
```

and `tagIsValid` definition would be:

```
function tagIsValid(tag) {
  tagChecked = document.createElement(tag).toString();
  return tagChecked != "[object HTMLUnknownElement]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (selector.indexOf('.') > 0) return 'tag.class';
return 'tag';
```

I think you can end it with that.